"compact" properties in kafka isn't working
I'm trying to compact my Kafka topics, but I still get duplication of the same key with the new modification made, so compacting isn't working. Here's the connector I'm using.
I also configured Kafka container like this but nothing:
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=1000
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.1
log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=1000 

    {
    "name": "connect-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "drop",
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": "1",
        "log.cleaner.enable": "true",
                "log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms":"1000",
                "log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio":"0.1",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "log.segment.ms": "1000",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "topic.prefix": "paraph",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory.inventory",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
        "transforms.unwrap.type":       "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.server.id": "184054",
        "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "name": "connect-source",
        "database.include.list": "database"
    }
}


Compaction doesn't guarantee only the latest message will be delivered. It guarantees that the last message is always kept. From the docs

Topic compaction guarantees that the latest value for each message key is always retained within the log of data contained in that topic.

And

Compaction in Kafka does not guarantee there is only one record with the same key at any one time. There may be multiple records with the same key, including the tombstone, because compaction timing is non-deterministic. Compaction is only done when the topic partition satisfies a few certain conditions, such as dirty ratio, or records in inactive segment files, etc.


and how can I keep only the last records of each key ?

It's not possible with Kafka. You'll need to build something yourself on top of it (e.g. having an inbox table in a database that stores the last message for a key) or you'll need to pick a different technology.

i picked apache flink and still can t seem to keep nly the updated record , any suggestions on what techno can I use to only retrieve the latest record from kafka topic after updates please  ?
